# MS Word giving 'Required Properties' error when opening from SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-online

Getting the 'Required Properties' error in MS Word when opening documents in the client from a SharePoint Online document library.

[image]

The library itself has added columns but none of them are required. Clicking on the button that says 'Edit Properties' none of them show as being required or any other type of messages as to what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the actual error that is occurring. The text 'To save to the server, correct the invalid or missing required properties' is also a link. Clicking on that link will take you to 'Info' settings page.

Click on 'Show All Properties'.

[image]

There you will find the exact item that is giving you the error and when you hover over the error, it should provide a little more insight into the issue so that you can save your file.
[image]

Comment: What if you get this error message and when looking at all the properties, it doesn't indicate any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer, but it might help someone who is trying to troubleshoot.

In our case, the issue was that we had a *Choice field* that was **Hidden** in our content type, and **did not allow Fill in Choices**.  The problem started when a new workflow was designed to enter different choice values that were not valid for this field (but for whatever reason, SharePoint allowed the workflow to save the custom value).

Now when the document was opened in the Word App, it would complain that there was a required field, but wouldn't give any hint as to which field this was.  After extensive testing, we found that Word was looking at the Choice  field: even though there was a value, it was considered invalid.

The issue was resolved immediately when toggling the "Allow Fill in Choices" setting to Yes for the column in SharePoint.

[image]